# Launch url from one activity on another activity

Tags: java, android, string, webview, nullpointerexception

I've been trying to make a small WebView app that lets the user search and load websites within it.

Currently my code looks promising in terms of the structure and the reference used, but I have stumbled upon an error which I can't seem to fix. Ive been looking for solutions on how to parse data as a string from my MainActivity class EditText to the WebView on my WebActivity class.

So far I've had no luck, I've tried several websites and have researched more into this but I have no clue what's going on. I even looked up similar answers regarding my situation on StackOverFlow but nothing has worked for me.

This Is the error I'm getting:

```
04-20 16:56:55.563: D/AndroidRuntime(32040): Shutting down VM
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040): Process: com.thearclabs.carpo, PID: 32040
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.thearclabs.carpo/com.thearclabs.carpo.WebActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at com.thearclabs.carpo.WebActivity.<init>(WebActivity.java:9)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
04-20 16:56:55.564: E/AndroidRuntime(32040):    ... 10 more
```

This is the code in my MainActivity's onCreate method:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
EditText searchInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchInput);
final String webUrl = searchInput.getText().toString();

searchInput.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("website", webUrl);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

And this is my WebActivity code:

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    String webUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("webUrl"); // error is coming from here, according the the error log.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("http://example.com" + webUrl);

        // webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `getIntent()` in any method like `onCreate` method instead of at class level:

```
    String webUrl = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
         webUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("website");
        //..your code here...
   }
```

Also make following changes :

**1.** Add `null` check before accessing `getExtras()` method.

**2.** Use same key which is used in previous Activity for adding data in Intent. currently you are using `webUrl` for getting value but in previous Activity `website` is used

Comment: Most of the code and help provided here fixes the error however the text in EditText is returning null.

Comment: @Pavillion: move `webUrl = searchInput.getText().toString();` line before `intent.putExtra("website", webUrl);` line

Comment: Thanks it works now, but now it seems to load the website on Google Chrome instead of loading it on my webView in my app.

Comment: @Pavillion: Also override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method and why you are appending other questions in comments? just finish this question by accepting any answer ans make another question for other issues

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I will look more into the OverrideUrlLoading method. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Please can you update webActivity there.

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {
       String webUrl="";
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
            Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();

            if(bundle!=null){
               webUrl = bundle.getString("webUrl"); 
            }

            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(webUrl)){
                 webView.loadUrl("http://example.com" + webUrl);
            }
            // webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this line

```
String webUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("webUrl");
```

after `onCreate()` method.

***EDIT:***

Move this line

```
final String webUrl = searchInput.getText().toString();
```

in to this condition

```
searchInput.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) { 
        String webUrl = searchInput.getText().toString(); 
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("website", webUrl);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now with no errors however there it s returning nothing (getting null) so basically anything thats typed in the EditText is returning as null.

Comment: It works but the webpage loads on chrome instead of it loading on my apps webveiw. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Since `getIntent()` method available in activity life cycle methods.therfore use

`String webUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("website");` // error is coming from here, according the the error log.

inside `onCreate` method as

```
String webUrl = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

       webUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("website");
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("http://example.com" + webUrl);

        // webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }
```

Comment: key is `website` instead of `webUrl`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use key to get data from intent. try below code

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
  String webUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("website"); // error is coming from here, according the the error log.
            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.loadUrl("http://example.com" + webUrl);

            // webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        }
    }
```

Comment: The EditText is returning null.

Comment: No like, the code works but anything that is entered in the EditText field is not passed to the next activity, in the url bar it just says http://null

Comment: try to get String from edittext String s=  editext,gettext().tostring() and pass s to activity using  intent.putExtra("website", s);